# Is it possible to match an entire path in Jolt shiftr?

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

Suppose I want to transform the following

**Original**

```
{
    "data": {
        "a": {
            "b": {
                "c": {
                    "value": 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For simplicity, say I just want to change `value` to `newValue`

**Result**

```
{
    "data" : {
        "a" : {
            "b" : {
                "c" : {
                    "newValue" : 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I could do that with the following Jolt spec:

**Spec**

```
[
    {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
            "data": {
                "a": {
                    "b": {
                        "c": {
                            "value": "&4.&3.&2.&1.newValue"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

But I feel like there should be a less verbose syntax... perhaps something like the following (which does not work):

**Desired Syntax... or something like it**

```
[
    {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
            "data.a.b.c.value": "data.a.b.c.newValue" // Even nicer to use & somehow
        }
    }
]
```

Is there any Jolt shiftr functionality that I'm missing that would make this nicer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an existing transform that does that.

Couple of issues:

1) the transform you desire is more of a "nudge" than a "shift".   In that you want to change a single value in the Json tree and leave the rest of the tree alone.   That doesn't exist in Jolt.
"shift" makes a new output map, and "copies" data from the input to the output.
I tried making shift write to the same input Json tree structure, but it is "dangerous" as it can easily run into ConcurrentModification exceptions.

2) The transform style you have laid out is nice for simple things, but I don't know how it would scale to all the complex stuff wildcard logic (*, [], &).

Answer (score 0):

It is the answer

```
{
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
        "jobInput": {
            "ai": {
                "common": {
                    "seed": "@(4,ai.model_structure.seed)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> @(4,ai.model_structure.seed)

upper sentence means backward 4step on json tree and use **seed** with this path(ai.model_structure.seed).